# Can one's genetics account for x% of their weight?

Tags: genetics, weight-loss

I have seen statements like this in various places: **"Such and such accounts for X percent of so and so"**. But it's not always clear what this means, how it is calculated or proven.

You will see this a lot, in particular, on [23andme.com](http://www.23andme.com), in your genetic report. If I'm 5' 11", and my genetics "accounts for 4%" of that...

Can one's genetics account for x% of their weight?

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics: questions here should be about being skeptical of notable unreferenced claims. I've reworded your question to be on-topic.

Comment: Your genome, existing in every single cell of your body, would reasonably comprise a certain % of your weight. But that's not really what's being asked, is it?

Comment: Please given one concrete example. But my general feeling is that people usually blame genetics for factors they could actually control, like physical activity and diet (apart from the fact that weight loss should not be a goal, but rather fat loss should be a goal).

Comment: Thanks for rewording, Sklivvz. I didn't know whether to post this one on statistics, skeptics, or who-knows-what. But I already had this account created...

Comment: On a humorous note: if I was born a fruit fly, I'd weigh less!

Comment: Imho, you're right, that such numbers are meaningless. Humans without genes don't exist, so you can't perform arithmetics with those numbers. The same counts for talent-vs-training numbers, power-vs-technique comparisons and similar situations, where statistic numbers are just used, to pretend some deeper knowledge, to impress the audience.

Answer (score 2):

“*A* is a gene for *X*” is a shortcut used by scientists when they actually mean to say “gene *A* modifies the expression of *X*, *all other things being equal*.” [1]
In particular, it means that an [allele](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allele) of gene *A* influences *X* compared to another allele of the same gene.

This means that if you hear “gene *A* accounts for x% of trait *T*” then what is really meant is that “gene *A* accounts for x% of the *difference* in expression of trait *T*, all other things being equal”.

On the flip side, this means that if x% of some trait are determined by genes then the rest of the variability comes from outside factors, such as nutrition.

[1]: see for example Richard Dawkins, *The Selfish Gene*

Comment: Do you want to express, that 2 persons (or 2000), using the same nutrition, will vary by x% of body weight, just because of their genes? Independent from their behaviour, whether they perform sports, or how they heat their environment? But isn't the likelihood to do sports, and to decide, which nutrition to use, and how much, influenced from genes too?

Comment: @user If those behaviours which influence trait X are influenced by genes then these genes are, by definition, also genes “for trait X”. Apart from that I said that the genes will have a *maximum* influence of x% on the trait (height). In fact, giving such a number is very hard for that very reason, because we don’t generally know which genes influence a trait indirectly. All we can measure (even in the best case) is the influence of *one* gene on a trait.

Comment: Your comment glosses over a point you made in the answer: If  someone says a gene accounts for 15% of thumb-length, they generally mean it accounts for 15% of the *variance* in thumb-lengths, which is much less than the length of your thumb multiplied by 0.15.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you are not asking for what the percentage heritability is, but whether it is valid to assign a percentage at all.

In situations like height, there is clearly a genetic factor (tall parents tend to have tall children) and an environmental factor (well-nourished generations tend to be taller than poorly-nourished generations). Weight has an even stronger environmental factor (as short-term weight-loss due to diets clearly shows).

In cases such as weight and height, while it may not be possible to predict the exact measure from genes alone, it is possible to account for a large part of the *variability*. So, **yes, there are valid statistical techniques to establish what percentage of the variability can be accounted for by a single factor** (or group of factors) like genetics.

I provide as evidence for this:

- [*Estimation of Individual Genetic and
  Environmental Factor Scores*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2184093), Boomsma DI, Molenaar PC, Orlebeke JF., Genet Epidemiol. 1990;7(1):83-91 [[PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.74.4485&rep=rep1&type=pdf)] - a paper discussing the statistical techniques used.
- [*Genetic factors contributing to obesity and body weight can act through mechanisms affecting muscle weight, fat weight, or both*](http://physiolgenomics.physiology.org/content/36/2/114.full), Gudrun A. Brockmann, Shirng-Wern Tsaih, Christina Neuschl, Gary A. Churchill, and Renhua Li, Physiol. Genomics January 2009 vol. 36 no. 2 114-126, doi: 10.​1152/​physiolgenomics.​90277.​2008 - An example of a paper using such techniques.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I understand what it means for some trait's variability to have a measurable genetic factor in general. But what does it mean to say *one person's* trait is accounted for by some unique percentage?

Comment: a) Tall parents having tall children can be taken as a social, cultural effect as well. b) I weight 80kg. If I stop eating, I will lose about 40 kg before dying, but if I eat, and eat, and eat, I might get 160 kg heavy. My genes can't do much against it - can they?

Comment: @user unknown: re: Height: I explicitly didn't claim that height was only genetic. However, I thought it would be generally accepted that it is highly attributable to genetics. The heights of adopted children would match their biological parents much more closely than their adoptive parents.

Comment: @user unknown: re: Weight. Agreed re: effects of under and over eating, but your genes could affect (i) how efficiently you convert your food to body mass, (ii) how much food you desire, (iii) the types of food you desire, (iv) how much activity you prefer to do/are capable of doing, (v) how much you are affected by peer pressure to adopt the socially-acceptable weight, (vi) how capable you are of overriding your desire to eat more/less and be more/less active, etc.

Comment: @Oddthinking: re (height): My parents are smaller than me and my brother/sister, while they were bigger than their parents/my grandparents; probably due to problems with nutrition in the youth of them because of WWI and WWII. But I guess, under same circumstances, the lengths would be more similar, that's right.

Comment: I understand cited papers, that they talk about populations, and the probability to have overweight with a special set of genes. But if you change the observed population (people/americans, americans/male americans, male persons/male persons between 30 and 40 and so on), the numbers will vary, but you can be part of different subgroups with different numbers. You can not individualize these numbers, imho.

Comment: @User Unk: I'm afraid I don't understand your objection. Perhaps in the question you could give a very specific example of a claim you think is inappropriate. (The one about 5' 11" being *only* 4% genetic seems artificial to me.) Alternatively, let's move it to chat.